# Is there a way to link unlinked objects?

Tags: modeling, materials

I am creating a 3D environment and there happens to be leaves and vines in the scene. I tried using Alt+D to create linked duplicates but it wasn't working so i used Shift+D to create just duplicates that aren't linked. The problem now is that I'm trying to apply the same materials and I have to go select all of them and apply separately. SO I have two questions here:

1. How come Alt+D didn't work? Blender clearly says Alt+D in the contextual menu but nothing happens when I use the hotkey.
2. Is there a way to link unlinked duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

Alt-D should work, in Object Mode? .. To create links (of various kinds), also in Object mode, select the target objects, and the source object last, so it's active, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

Then select the aspect of the source you would like the targets to link to. In this case, 'Materials'.

Comment: yeah I didn't get Alt+D to work. I'm wondering if it clashes with another system-wide hotkey but wasn't able to find what it is. It works if I change the hotkey but just not ALT+D.